# Inserting several pictures into MS Word at once without using Media Browser

Tags: ms-office, photos.app, photos

In Microsoft Word 2011, we can either "insert picture from file" or "insert from photo (media) browser". For users who do not have pictures stored in iPhoto or Photobooth, we are forced to use "insert picture from file" method, which only allows for one picture to be added at a time.  How can I add more than one picture at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what alternative you are wanting besides those two options, but you might add a smart folder somewhere that filters by kind "image" which would let you insert image from file that is sort of like a photo browser.

Alternatively there is a very old tip (like 2008) in [this Mac OSX Hints thread](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080608080454833) that says you should be able to add folders to the media browser by dragging them from the finder into the media browser window. I have no idea if this still works.

Comment: Do you mean adding a smart folder somewhere through finder? I will check this out.

Comment: I can confirm that the dragging a folder into the media browser still works for M$ Word 2011 in OSX 10.9. To drag the folder from finder to Word media browser, I suggest first drag the folder, then alt+tab to switch to Word 2011 and drag the folder to the media browser window opened earlier.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround, going through TextEdit:

1. Open TextEdit, and create a new file.
2. In TextEdit, add the images to the new file.
3. In TextEdit, select all of your images and copy them (cmd-A, cmd-C).
4. In Word, paste the images (cmd-V).

This will result in all of the images being pasted into Word, which you can then manipulate as you normally would.

Comment: Would this actually affect the image quality? I've read somewhere that it's recommended to add pictures using M$ Word "Insert a picture" instead of copy and paste. Anyway, your tip is invaluable too! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While far less than perfect, one of the suggestions above  worked for me on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.11.2 & MS Word for Mac 2011 (ver. 14.5.8, the latest as of December, 2015):

WORK-AROUND PROCEDURE:
First put any photos that you wish to use in Word documents in a folder (or folders) in Finder.

Next, open a Word document; then, go to MEMU > INSERT, Photo Browser (open, and leave it open, displayed on monitor)

Then, drag the folder (or folders) into the upper section of the Photo Browser window. (The images in a selected folder should appear in the lower window.)

Next, drag am image into the Word document.

After this, one can leave the folders in place and add or delete files as needs change. Also, can add more folders. The browser accepted folders, but not images unless they were in a folder.

This is a very cumbersome task, but is a "work around." For the life of me I cannot understand why Apple did such a thing. Hopefully, they will correct this serious problem in a soon-coming update.

Answer (score 0):

The TextEdit method worked for me, but only after changing a setting from plain text to rich text format (RTFD).  Only then could I attach the images. 
So if you're stymied, that's something to try.